# Knockout SyntaxError: Unable to parse bindings in foreach loop

Tags: javascript, html, mvvm, knockout.js

I am using knockout and trying to implement this logic to render my html page.

```
<span data-bind="text: $data[($root.gridColumnCollection()[1][0]).field]"></span>
```

gridColumnCollection is collection of some data.
$root.gridColumnCollection()[1][0]).field holds value which is equal to 'CompanyName'

And I am getting this error:

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unable to parse bindings.
Bindings value: text: $data[($root.gridColumnCollection()[1][0]).field]
Message: Unexpected token )**

---

But, if I am hard coding the value the page is getting rendered.

```
<span data-bind="text: $data['CompanyName']"></span>
```

The above code is working fine.

Can anyone help me with this or suggest me what's wrong?? As I don't want to use hard-coded values.

Comment: Did any debug for this?

Comment: what do you mean by debug?

Comment: Alas! You are not aware of debugging. Anyways, see this specifically for KnockOut! http://www.knockmeout.net/2013/06/knockout-debugging-strategies-plugin.html

Comment: Boss I am aware about debugging!! I was just asking, were you looking for any specific point?

one more point if I write this code

     <span data-bind="foreach: $root.gridColumnCollection()[1][0]">
     <span data-bind="text: $parent[field]"></span>
     </span>

then also code is working!!

Comment: Try using <span data-bind="text: $data[$root.gridColumnCollection()[1][0].field]"></span>. I have removed the bracket that you have added before $root and also its closing one after [0].

Comment: I have already tried this, but it is not working. :(